# http 400 bad request at login.microsoftonline.com with internet explorer but after refreshing the page the login works

Tags: internet-explorer, office365

When trying to login on https://login.microsoftonline.com the `Internet Explorer (11.3274.14393.0)` correctly establishing a connection to our STS with the correct internal DNS record. After applying the creds the IE shows the bad request message. After simply refreshing the page mit F5 it is working just fine and its logging in automatically in the same session.

Our STSserver is member of the Intranet Zone.
On Google Chrome the login works as expected.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to clear the cache and cookies of the IE browser and again try to login to Microsoft site to see whether it fix this issue or not. Let us know about your testing results. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I did. Same error.

Comment: Is there anything on that machine which can modify that request? If yes, then it can be the cause for it. Check whether all the security zones has same level of settings applied or not. For testing purpose, try to make it same and test. also test with lower level of settings.